# Reducing the need for JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing several small things in JavaScript, notably a `mousemove` event, and a AJAX call. I don't believe that two things should necessitate loading the ~25KB that is jQuery. Add in the fact that I want as *few* external dependencies as possible and necessitating jQuery isn't something I want to do.

Is there a primer / tutorials on rewriting calls between a JavaScript library and pure JavaScript?

- `$('element')`
- `$.get()`

Answer (score 5):

For the selector part `$("element")`, you might as well use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is the same library used in jQuery and other JS framworks, and is only 4kb (minified and gzipped).

As for the $.get() call, a simple wrapper around the native XMLHttpRequest object should suffice, depending on what features exactly do you want to provide. Check the [Mozilla Developper Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) docs for some pointers.

Comment: Agreed.  AJAX requests can be written directly against XMLHttpRequest; only the constructor needs a cross-browser wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) for its selectors magic. I can't remember if it weighs 3 or 7 kB but it's a standalone library

Answer (score 0):

You can study the library code, and write your own IF you want to.